# Passing variables from one modal window to another in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, parameters, modal-dialog, session-variables

I have an asp.net application where I need to pass values from one modal windown to another modal window. I have tried session variables, but they return null 50% of the time.

What would be another alternative to pass paramaters from a modal window to another?

Cookies are not an option.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of modals?  Are these internally iframes, or is the content inline?  Seems like iframe scenario where it performs a navigational request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the only reliable way to do this is through javascript:

the child window can can set a value in the parent like this:

```
window.parent.setValue(x);
```

with this in the parent:

```
function setValue(x)
{
     document.getElementById(<% HiddenField1.ClientID %>).value = x;
}
```

The child has now set a value in the parent window which can be accessed form the parent's codebehind via the control HiddenField1.